# How to host a web app at Amazon WS

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, hosting

I have web app that is created using PHP and for DB I'm using phpMyAdmin SQL database. The app is hosted on Linux based server, for FTP access I'm using FIleZila and NotePad++ and for DB access I'm using phpMyAdmin.

Now i need to host this app on Amazon WS. I have credentials for Amazon WM account, but I don't know how to start. I have take a look at the documentation, but I can not figure out how to set up the DB and then to set up the site so it can be hosted at their server.

Can you guys give me some tips, tutorials, or something that will help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to deploy an ec2 instance, they'll give you ssh access. You can then access it with putty and then install LAMP on it. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu there's a nice tutorial on how to install it. Once you got that done you can upload your app and set up your database. You will also need to get a domain name and sort out the dns for it. You can do that with Amazon's route 53

Comment: Also, I've used amazon's cloud services before and although they are very good, I personally prefer digital ocean. It is easier to set up and their prices are a lot more straight forward, you also get better value for your money. $5 gets you a nice droplet with them whereas $5 will only get you a micro instance in amazon, which as far as I remember does not have enough memory to run mysql without reducing the memory allocation you give it. It also dies if a process takes too long (5 seconds or something) because you only get bursts of processing power